# expected: java.lang.Long<1> but was: java.lang.Integer<1>

Tags: java, junit

I'm using JUnit to test some code.

This section below:

```
    assertEquals(query.get(0).get("FEEDBACK_ID"), feedbackValues.getFeedbackId());
```

Results in the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.Long<1> but was: java.lang.Integer<1>
```

Which is fine...

My question is, how can I convert this object:

```
query.get(0).get("FEEDBACK_ID")
```

Into an Integer in order to avoid the test failing? I know it would be easier to convert the item on the right into a long, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: If one is `Integer` and the other is `Long`, then it will be better to test both values as `long` rather than `int`. Use `Number#longValue` for the `assertEquals`.

Comment: `...but I don't want to do that.` The simplest solution is to comment out the entire line then. Test passes, job done. (P.s.: this isn't serious advice of course, just a bit of a joke. But the serious point I'm trying to make is that if you're willing to hack your tests instead of fixing the problem, you might as well do away with testing altogether. Yes, in this case you can argue it's neither here nor there but it's a slippery slope.)

Comment: @AlexR very bad idea...

Comment: @biziclop  Casting your int to a long is not a hack, it's a valid change. Casting your long to an int is a hack and shouldn't give you much security to the validity of your JUnit test.

Comment: @Kon Any time you're willing to change the correct test logic to suit the quirks of the UUT rather than the other way around is hacking the test. Why aren't the types identical? Either the query returns the wrong type or `feedbackValues.getFeedbackId()`, there's no third option.  Of course in this case the practical consequences of a sneaky cast in the test logic are likely to be nil, but in general it's a bad idea.

Comment: @biziclop The correct test logic is intended to, in this case, compare that two values are equal. That's the intended goal. Variable types differing do not preclude equality, right? So from the standpoint of a valid comparison it only makes sense to upcast your integer value. Alternatively you need to re-evaluate what this condition SHOULD be testing. If it should be testing for same type, then your test is failing correctly. That's my take.

Comment: @Kon, So, I've already tried casting it and assigning it to another variable, in that case there's an error saying "Long cannot be cast to Integer", if I do it in the same line it says it's "ambiguous". Is there any way around this?

Comment: @Kon Fair enough, and only OP knows which is the case here. The general point I'm trying to make is that the "Oh, the test has failed, I must change it so it passes." line of thinking is dangerous.

Comment: @biziclop Agree with that 100%.

Comment: @navlag You should never cast your long to an int. You should, in this case (and in my opinion), cast your int to a long. This is a lossless cast since a long has 64 bit of information and a int has 32, so you will never lose anything.

Answer (score 1):

The very thing you want to achieve is wrong, so the only valid answer is : don't do this. Basically, you are trying to add a behaviour to your method just to match your test. What are you testing in this case ? Certainly not the method. Even if there's little chance it happens, casting down to `int` might result in an integer overflow and screw up your test.

A test should not add additional transformations to the output of the tested method, otherwise who tests these additional transformation ? Why the API does not return the type you want to manipulate ?

Your methods should return the same type, or you should be promoting the `int` result to `long`, because it is safe.